# How to equalize card-img sizes if include video

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make sure the size of the pictures and videos in the card-deck are equal

```php
<div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#"><img src="./../trier.jpg" alt="foto" class="card-img img-fluid"></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aut quod vero vitae quaerat ipsum at, temporibus odio. Nemo veniam rem consectetur totam debitis officia impedit similique cumque nobis culpa!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent text-center">
                <p class="text-muted">BLABLABLABLABLABLA</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <a href = "#"><div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1"><iframe src="./../trialVideo.mp4" class = "card-img img-fluid" controls></iframe></div> </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aut quod vero vitae quaerat ipsum at, temporibus odio. Nemo veniam rem consectetur totam debitis officia impedit similique cumque nobis culpa!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent text-center">
                <p class="text-muted">BLABLABLABLABLABLA</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#"><img src="./../trier.jpg" alt="foto" class="card-img img-fluid"></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas aut quod vero vitae quaerat ipsum at, temporibus odio. Nemo veniam rem consectetur totam debitis officia impedit similique cumque nobis culpa!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent text-center">
                <p class="text-muted">BLABLABLABLABLABLA</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Output of my code : 
https://ibb.co/b15gqhZ

Comment: What are the CSS rules you give to `.card`, `.card-body`, `.card-footer`, ? I think you don't need PHP tag for this question

Comment: You will need to contain your images, and videos in a `div` with specified `width` and `height` , your images are not contained by anything but the `anchor` and  `.card`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your css:

```css
.card-img top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try, but should I add a 'card-img-top' tag to pictures and videos?

Comment: or directly apply it to all img tags until you reach the wished result

Comment: very plentiful, could you please help me with a little trouble on javascript?

Comment: Sure, i can try. I'm not an expert, but I'd love to help.